# Capped Arrays in MongoDB 2.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

MongoDB 2.4 introduces Capped Arrays:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#limit-number-of-elements-in-an-array

Considering the following document structure (with nested array):

```js
thread  { 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5191039d48ef54c24a000002"),
  "messages" : [
    {"content" : "hello", "sent_at": "ISODate("2013-05-13T15:15:44.162Z")},
    {"content" : "hi again", "sent_at": "ISODate("2013-05-13T15:15:48.162Z")}
  ]
}
```

Using the new capped array feature, How can I remove the oldest message when a new one (51th for example) is added ?

*In other words, how can I limit the nested array "messages" to 50 items ?*

Comment: the docs show an example of how to do this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/#pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do something like this: (based on the example [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/))

```js
db.thread.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5191039d48ef54c24a000002") },
    { $push: { 
        messages: { 
            $each : [{ message }],
            $sort: { sent_at: 1 },
            $slice: -50
        },
    }},
);
```

Comment: you sure you are using mongodb 2.4 not 2.2 ?

Comment: how to do the same using Morphia?